# Mysterious <P> Tag showing in FF and Chrome

Tags: html, paragraph

See this link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IEpGz

If you use the code inspector in both FF and Chrome, you will see the following (concatenated):

```
<p>
  Search Engine 
</p>


<p>
</p>
```

Yet if you CTRL+U to view the source, you see this:

```
<p>
  Search Engine 

</p>
```

The latter is the intended result. I'm not sure where the extra `<p>` is coming from?

Comment: Have you tried it on your local computer. It could be that codepen is adding it, perhaps for layout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a consequence of an attempted recovery from invalid HTML.

A `<p>` cannot contain `<div>`.

Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: Interesting - I pasted the code into a validator and it never indicated that issue. But that clearly solved it. Thanks!